# Random Crashes and Critical Errors with Toshiba SSD - BHDrvx64 the Cause?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, crash, bsod

I recently bought and installed the Toshiba Q Series Pro (THNSNJ256GCST) 256GB SSD into my laptop. Whenever I boot up in the mornings, the OS (Windows 7 Pro x64) will have random critical errors stating that it is unable to access important system files and eventually reboots. After several reboots, the system finally remains stable and no errors or anything. This happens every other day.

I tried using `sfc /scannow` with no problems. I did a memory diagnostics as well with no errors. I also have System Mechanic Pro installed, which scans for problems in the background. I checked the Event Viewer and just before every crash, this event is logged

> File System Filter 'BHDrvx64' (6.1, ‎2013‎-‎12‎-‎05T17:05:28.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager.

Maybe it has something to do with Norton AntiVirus using a conflicting driver.

I don't have any minidumps to show since my page file was turned off.

Comment: Try running a smart tool and check the cable attaching your SDD is ok (test a different cable)

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed have to do with Norton as the driver is related to BHDrvx64.sys BASH Driver from Symantec Corporation.

I would remove Norton (or update to current) and use MSE in its place.  I would also update the SSD firmware.

Comment: I searched the Toshiba site and found no firmware anywhere. Where can I find the firmware?